# iOS: How to check a given Class is a kind of UIViewController class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiviewcontroller

I am writing a method that returns a view controller instance for a given view controller class, but I need to make sure the class passed in is actually a view controller class:

```
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerWithClass:(Class)cls nibName:(NSString *)nibName
{
    if (cls is kind of UIViewController subclass)
        return [[[cls alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibName bundle:nil] autorelease];
    return nil;
}
```

I cannot compare the name of the class since `cls` may not be UIViewController.

edit:

Sorry I meant inside the method, how do I check if `cls` is a kind of UIViewController subclass

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if ([cls isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {


   //Your code

}
```

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer I just want to clarify that all the other answers that use isKindOfClass method are wrong, isKindOfClass does not work for objects with type 'Class' (as cls is in this example), [[CDMyClass class] isKindOfClass:[CDMyClass class]] returns NO also [CDMyClass isKindOfClass:[CDMyClass class]] returns NO. In order to use a receiver that is a type of Class you should use isSubclassOfClass

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code.

```
if ([cls isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class object representing the Objective-C class to be tested then use [`+ (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a) which returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class. (required)

```
if([cls isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
{
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have a class object which is a subclass of—or identical to class to be tested then use [`+ (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiving class is a subclass of, or identical to, a given class.

```
if([cls isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check This out
if([youViewControllerObject isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
{
    NSLog(@"isViewcontroller Class");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a little late, but since you want to check the class of a *Class Object* (not an instance of a class), the following is the appropriate test:

```
if(cls == [UIViewController class]) {
   // Whatever ...
}
```

Comment: no, they don't want to check that it's exactly `UIViewController`, they want to know if it's `UIViewController` or a subclass thereof